# Convert Strings in CSV files to floats or intergers with using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a neural network with tensorflow and keras to predict fatalities in car accidents in Canada. I have imported my dataset from a CSV file and set one of the columns as the label. Most of the columns just contain floats but some of them such as gender contains strings like M or F. Is there a way I can convert these strings to floats?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
for r in df.rows:
    print(type(r))
y_train = df["C_SEV"].copy()
x_train = df.drop(columns=["C_SEV"])


print(df["C_SEV"])

x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_train.flatten()
```

Comment: This short pandas tutorial on categoricals can help: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#categoricals

Comment: For binary variables, something like: `df['is_Male'] = pd.get_dummies(df.Gender)['M']`, or just `map({'M': 1, 'F': 0})`